# running serve give me "ErrorException"

Tags: php, laravel-artisan

yesterday the app works great, change in setting the currency.
And sudenly the app dont work.

try to "composer update" and it gives me error.

```
{"error":{"type":"ErrorException","message":"Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; pointLocation has a deprecated constructor","file":"\/app\/pointInPolygon.php","line":13}}
```

Search on internet, but cant find why the error is showing.

Comment: The linked question is the first result when you google the error message. PHP/4 is vastly outdated (more than 15 years), please let it die.

Comment: I have tryed with version 5.6 and 7.0

Comment: That's the problem. You are using an outdated syntax. You need to upgrade your code or, if it's a third party libtary' find a modern replacement.